# Android null object reference error reading XML file: why?

Tags: forms, xamarin

I got this error when a click the button to take a picture . this was working just fine couple weeks ago . so I dont know whats going on . 
error 1 :

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
this is how my manifest looks :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.myapp.pers" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Myapp">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your api key here " />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android....." android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

error 2: if I add this

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.myapp.pers.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
```

this is the error I got

```
/Users/...../Droid/obj/Debug/android/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml: Error APT0000: 21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/file_paths'). (APT0000) (myapp.pers.Droid)
```

Comment: `No resource found .... xml/file_paths` : It is telling you the problem, you do not have a file named `file_paths` in your Resources `xml` directory. That xml-based file needs to contain the provider paths your app is supporting....

Comment: You might be using "view" instead of "View"

Answer (score 1):

I got my own answer. Just to create a folder named xml inside resources, add a new empty class named `file_paths.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```